# Three cities, four roads, one railway: a probabilistic traveling problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Two roads join Ayton to Beaton, and two further roads join Beaton to the City. Ayton is directly connected to the City by a railway. All four roads and the railway are each independently blocked by snow with probability $p$. I am at Ayton.

(a) Find the probability that I can drive to the City.

(b) Find the probability that I can travel to the City.

(c) Given that I can travel to the City, what is the probability that the railway is blocked?

**MY ATTEMPT**

(a) There are two possibilities to drive from Ayton to Beaton. The probability that both roads are blocked by snow is given by $p^{2}$. Therefore the probability to reach Beaton from Ayton by road is given by $(1-p^{2})$. The same applies to the travel from Beaton to City. Since both events are independent, the sought probability is given by $(1-p^{2})^{2}$.

However I am unable to proceed from here. Can somebody help me to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from what you have done, the probability you cannot drive to the city is $1-(1-p^2)^2$
So the probability you cannot travel to the city by any means is $$p(1-(1-p^2)^2)$$
Then the probability you can travel to the city by some means or other is 1 - this.

Then use conditional probability formula for the last part...